# How to create an NSDictionary that contains an array for every key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I wanted to know how (if it is possible) to create an NSDictionary that holds an NSArray for every key.

Something like that:

@"FirstKey"   - [0], [1], [2], [3]
@"SecondKey"  - [0], [1], [2], [3]
@"ThirdKey"   - [0], [1], [2], [3]
@"FourthKey"  - [0], [1], [2], [3]

Hope you got the idea, thanks ahead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `NSArray` instances (or any other collection) as values of an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[d setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], 
               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
               ...,
               nil]
     forKey:@"FirstKey"];
[d setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], 
               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
               ...,
               nil]
     forKey:@"SecondKey"];
//etc.
```

Alternatively, if you don't have too many keys/values:

```
NSArray *values1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], 
                    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
                    ...,
                    nil];
NSArray *values2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0], 
                    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
                    ...,
                    nil];
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     values1, @"FirstKey",
                     values2, @"SecondKey",
                     ...,
                     nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

That's totally possibly.  Simplest way is to create your NSArray and then just add that as the object for the key to your NSDictionary

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two", nil];
[myDictionary setObject:myArray forKey:@"FirstKey"];
```

Comment: Is there any way to create that in the instance method?

Comment: Yes, just use `[NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",nil], @"FirstKey", nil];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store any object in a dictionary.  For numeric values you will need to store them as NSValue or NSNumber objects.

Comment: I want to create an NSDictionary where every key is a string and holds an NSArray

Comment: Yes, an NSArray is just another kind of object.